# Change Kendo Grid column binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have some radio buttons on my page and I want to bind one of my Kendo Grid's columns according to the user's selection, and then refresh the grid.

This is my javascript code:

```
function change(c) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
    switch (c) {
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
        case 1:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to show/hide the right columns. See the [API definition](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-hideColumn).

```
function change(c) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
    switch (c) {
        case 2:
            grid.hideColumn("Column1");
            grid.showColumn("Column2");
            break;
        case 3:
            grid.showColumn("Column3");
            break;
        default:
        case 1:
            grid.hideColumn(3);
            grid.showColumn(4);
            break;
    }
}
```

A while ago I posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26112267/2450507), explaining different ways to hide columns.