# KendoReact Grid show wrong column

Tags: reactjs, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I'm working on the Grid in `"@progress/kendo-react-gri*"` for my project and I'm getting problem like this. My data have five fields but I just want to display two of it so I just define three column in tsx file like this:

```
<Grid style={{ height: "400px" }} data={products}>
                  <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40px" />
                  <Column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250px" />
                </Grid>
```

This is my data:

> {
>       "ProductID" : 2,
>       "ProductName" : "Chang",
>       "ReorderLevel" : 25,
>       "Discontinued" : false,
>       "Category" : {
>           "CategoryID" : 1,
>           "CategoryName" : "Beverages",
>           "Description" : "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
>       }

but it still display five column that content all field of my data.

[image]
 Anyone have solution for this?

**PS: I tried with wrapper lib but got the same issue.**

Comment: Could you confirm that you are using the latest version of the package?

Comment: Hi. Lastest version solve this issue for me. I forgot to reply you.

Comment: Can you update the package name to show the full name?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide some columns then use below code for this :
In kendo ui : Please use **hidden:true**

Reference Link : https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.hidden

In kendo React : Please use **show: false**

Reference Link : [How Can I Hide Kendo UI Grid Columns using JavaScript, React, Angular, Vue or ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112233/how-can-i-hide-kendo-ui-grid-columns-using-javascript-react-angular-vue-or-as)

Thanks,